# Github pages can't save

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm about to save my gh page and there is a message which said "GitHub Pages is currently disabled. Select a source below to enable GitHub Pages for this repository." and I can't click save

[image: Here's the screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and my solution is quite simple:

1. After my first commit, 'Save' button is disabled.
   [image]
2. Click the dropdown menu, select 'None' in the dropdown menu. Now, you can see the 'Save' button is enabled. Save this selection.
   [image]
3. Again, click the dropdown menu, select the branch from which you want to build the site, e.g. main. Now, you can see the 'Save' button is enabled. Save this selection.
   [image]
4. Refresh the current page a few minutes later, and your page is already served.
   [image]

Answer (score 4):

I still don't know why is this happening, but as a quick fix: Inspect the button and remove the `disabled` attribute.